# ObservableCollection - removing items by looping through vs .Clear()

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection which is bound to some ItemsControl (FlipView) as its ItemsSource. I was having an issue with the scrolling on a touch device where the entire FlipView would disappear as soon as user touches the screen and it would reappear when the finger is removed from the screen. So to fix that, I had to work around it by clearing the collection whenever I had to refresh it (instead of re-instantiating it). I noticed that the same issue (with touch) was occurring when I used .Clear() in order to clear the collection but when I looped through the collection and removed the items one-by-one the issue was resolved.

So, I am still not clear as to what is the difference b/w these two ways of clearing the ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly internally the `ObservableCollection` maintains a `IList` which is assigned an instance of `List`. The `ObservableCollection.Clear` method eventually calls `Clear` on the interal list and that `List.Clear` method then uses `Array.Clear` to clear the items.